# How to read audio bytes and convert to 16K mono PCM16LE format in python

Tags: python, wave

I was trying to convert a `.raw` file to `.wav`.
I used `wave` package

```
import wave

with open("inpu.raw", "rb") as in_file:
    audio_data = in_file.read()

    with wave.open("output.wav", "wb") as out_file:
        out_file.setnchannels(1)
        out_file.setsampwidth(2)
        out_file.setframerate(16000)
        out_file.writeframesraw(audio_data)
```

Here I am applying `setchannels` and `setframerate` to convert the audio to 16K mono.

But I need apply the same conversion to an incoming audio bytes. Below is a method written in Tornado.

```
def on_message(self, message):
        assert self.worker is not None   
        
        if isinstance(message, str):
            self.worker.write_message(message, binary=False)
        else:
            self.worker.write_message(message, binary=True)
```

`message` here is `<bytes>` coming from client.
How can I feed the `message` to `wave` package to convert to 16 K mono format
or any alternative ways to do this ?